# Downloading images and captions with JSON in xcode

Tags: objective-c, json

I have googled this numerous times, with lots of different phrasing, but nothing seems to have exactly what I am after.

What I want to do is to download images and captions into a NSArray with JSON. I do not want to save these images, only display them in a UICollectionView. It would be much easier to be able to download multiple images using the same URL, not just 1 image per URL.

Since I am a fairly newbie programmer, I only know how to use NSURLRequest. This is some of my code:

```
NSString *getDataURL = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"URL and a couple of perams", var, var2] stringByReplacingOccurencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%20"];
NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:getDataURL]];
[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:req delegate:self];
```

And then a bit later on in the connectionDidFinishLoading: method:

```
NSArray *dataArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:nil error:nil]; // variable 'data' is an NSMutableData declared in .h
```

Please advise on what to do, or even if it's possible!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
-(void) loadImageAtURL:(NSString*)url {
    NSURL *requestURL = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:url];
    NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:requestURL cachePolicy:nil timeoutInterval:45.0];
    connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    imageData = [[[NSMutableData alloc] init] retain];
}
```

And handle response in NSURL delegate methods like:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection
    didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    [imageData appendData:data];
}


- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)aConnection {

    // RELEASE THE CONNECTION
    [connection release];

    // CREATE NEW UIIMAGE FROM THE DATA
    UIImage *image = [[[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData] retain];
    [imageData release];

    [yourImageView setImage:image]; 

    [image release];

}



- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection
  didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    // Handle error
}
```

Hope these methods will give you direction how to carry out things. You make the JSON handling as per your API response in `didReceiveData:(NSData *)data` and use that data later in `connectionDidFinishLoading:`

Comment: Thanks, this looks great however will it allow me to fetch text as well? What I do now with text is parse it into a NSArray and read it off like this: '[[myarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Image"];'

Comment: @nanothread59: Like I said you can parse any of the data from your API in the didReceiveData:(NSData *)data delegate, what prevents you to fetch the text? :) yes, you can fetch text if it is there in the json response

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand exactly what you are trying to ask but if your goal is to get a list of images/captions using JSON give AFNetworking a try

https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking